# gwt request (via RequestBuilder) causing response to be treated as JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, gwt

The following code

```
    RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, URL.encode("http://localhost:8080/xxxx/yyyy"));

try {
          Request request = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
            public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
            }

            public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
            }

          });
        } catch (RequestException e) {
          possiblePages.clear(); possiblePages.addItem("could not connect to server");        
        }
```

Written in GWT/Java compiles to javascript that gives the following error (shown in firebug)

```
syntax error
[Break on this error] begin
```

"begin" is the first line of the text file that is returned from the url, so I see where it is getting it from, but why is it being treated as JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Matt, I have 2 ideas that you can try:

1. Try explicitly setting the
   response's content type to
   "text/html" or "text/xml" in your
   servlet and see if that helps.
2. Try clearing firefox's cache? I've
   seen a few rare cases where old gwt
   javascript gets cached and conflicts
   with new code.